# React-Snap with Create-React-App and Service Workers

Tags: react-snap

So, my understanding is that react-snap as per its features "Works out-of-the-box with create-react-app - no code-changes required."

I read through the documentation and I see that it required some adjusting to work with Google Analytics which I implemented.

However, it also suggests changes to be made if one is going to use the default service worker that comes with CRA.

https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap#service-workers

However, what is confusing is that it seems one has to perform a EJECT in order to make the necessary change.

> > navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',

You need to change this to an un-prerendered version of index.html - 200.html, otherwise you will see index.html flash on other pages (if you have any). See Configure sw-precache without ejecting for more information.

My question is - and note I am quite novice - does one have to eject? I kinda want to keep things simple. The only place I could find this line was in WebPack. navigateFallback

Also, if I don't see the negative side of the flashes on pages as per the documentation, is it okay to omit this step or will it have issues on other things?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is more than a year old, I'd like to take the opportunity as I've been able to implement service workers in react-snap (although with a varying degree of success).

Here's stereobooster's reference in GitHub:
https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap/blob/master/doc/recipes.md#configure-sw-precache-without-ejecting

You can configure it without ejecting. What you need to do is the following:
Download and install `sw-precache` and `ugfify-js`:

```
  npm install sw-precache uglify-js --save-dev
  or
  yarn add sw-precache uglify-js -D
```

Then, in your package.json add the following entries:
(Replace the build script with the following)

```
"scripts": {
    "generate-sw": "sw-precache --root=build --config scripts/sw-precache-config.js && uglifyjs build/service-worker.js -o build/service-worker.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build && react-snap && yarn run generate-sw"
}
```

Then, create a folder in the root level (next to your package.json) called `scripts`
and add `sw-precache-config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
  // a directory should be the same as "reactSnap.destination",
  // which default value is `build`
  staticFileGlobs: [
    "build/static/css/*.css",
    "build/static/js/*.js",
    "build/shell.html",
    "build/index.html"
  ],
  stripPrefix: "build",
  publicPath: ".",
  // there is "reactSnap.include": ["/shell.html"] in package.json
  navigateFallback: "/shell.html",
  // Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219
  navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
  // By default, a cache-busting query parameter is appended to requests
  // used to populate the caches, to ensure the responses are fresh.
  // If a URL is already hashed by Webpack, then there is no concern
  // about it being stale, and the cache-busting can be skipped.
  dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
  // configuration specific to this experiment
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: /api/,
      handler: "fastest"
    }
  ]
};
```

Note, if you're not using an app-shell but you're loading the whole page (Meaning there's no dyanmic content), replace where it says `navigateFallback: "/shell.html"` with `navigateFallback: "/200.html"`

This basically allows you to cache the entire page

You can look for more information here:
https://github.com/stereobooster/an-almost-static-stack

One thing that I'd recommend to check (I'm close to start that process as well) is the [workbox-sw](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw).

### What to do if React-Snap fails

> error at / TypeError: Cannot read property 'ok' of null

Or

> ERROR: The process with PID 38776 (child process of PID 26920) could not be terminated.                                                                         \node_modules\minimalcss\src\run.js:13:35)
> Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

You may get these infamous errors. I don't know exactly what causes them, but I know they're mentioned [here](https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap/issues/314), and [here](https://github.com/peterbe/minimalcss/issues/269). In this case, delete the `build` folder, open a new terminal window, and try again.

If the problem still persists, then break down the script:

Do:

```js
"scripts": {
  "build":  "react-scripts build"
  "postbuild": "react-snap",
  "generate-sw": "sw-precache --root=build --config scripts/sw-precache-config.js && uglifyjs build/service-worker.js -o build/service-worker.js",
}
```

And try running them independently.